# Быстрая сортировка и многопоточность C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность, сортировка, инспекция-кода, синхронизация

Решил реализовать быструю сортировку(Quick Sort) с использованием многопоточности C++(thread) и портфеля задач.

> Метод портфеля задач заключается в поддержании очереди из задач.
>   Каждый свободный поток берёт задачу из портфеля, выполняет её, при
>   необходимости генерируя новые подзадачи и помещая их в портфель.

Алгоритм вроде бы работает, но у меня складывается такое впечатление, что на одном потоке работает быстрее, чем, например, на 2-х или 4-х. Пожалуйста, подскажите что не так в моём коде? Быть может я что-то намудрил с синхронизацией?

Вот код:

```
    #include <thread>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <mutex>
    #include <condition_variable>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <queue>
    #include <vector>
    #include <set>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <algorithm>

    //очередь задач(сюда помещаются индексы после разбиения, т.е l и r 
    queue< pair<int, int> > tasks;
    //мьютекс для очереди и множества
    mutex q_mutex, s_mutex;
    //условная переменная
    condition_variable cv;
    //множество
    set<int> ss;

    //алгоритм разбиения
    template <typename T>
    int partition(vector<T> &arr, int l, int r)
    {
        T tmp = arr[r]; //опорный элемент
        int i = l - 1;

        for (int j = l; j <= r - 1; j++)
            if (arr[j] < tmp)
            {
                i++;
                swap(arr[i], arr[j]);       
            }

        swap(arr[i + 1], arr[r]);
        i++;
        return i;
    }

    //быстрая сортировка
    template <typename T>
    void quick_sort(vector<T> &arr)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> u_lock(q_mutex); //блокируем мьютекс

            //массив отсортирован
            if ( ss.size() == arr.size() ) //u_lock.unlock()
                return;

            //Если очередь не пуста, берем из неё задачу 
            if ( tasks.size() > 0 )
            {
                pair<int, int> cur_task = tasks.front();            
                tasks.pop();

                int l = cur_task.first, r = cur_task.second;        

                if (l < r)
                {
                    int q = partition(arr, l, r); //сделали разбиение

                    //Добавили в множество
                    s_mutex.lock();
                    ss.insert(q);
                    ss.insert(l);
                    ss.insert(r);
                    s_mutex.unlock();

                    //добавили в очередь задачи для левого и правого конца
                    tasks.push( make_pair(l, q - 1) );
                    tasks.push( make_pair(q + 1, r) );

                    //разбудили ожидающий поток
                    cv.notify_one();
                }
            }
            else
                //Если очередь пуста, то ожидаем
                cv.wait(u_lock);
        }
    }

    //Размер массива
    const int ARR_SIZE = 100000;
    //Количество потоков
    const int THREAD_COUNT = 8;
    //массив потоков
    thread thrs[THREAD_COUNT];

    //генерируем массив чисел
    void generate_arr(vector<int> &arr)
    {
        srand(time( NULL ));

        std::generate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](){return rand() % 10000; });
    }

    //проверка на сортировку
    bool is_sorted(const vector<int> &arr)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; i++)
            if ( ! (arr[i] <= arr[i + 1]) ) 
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    int main()
    {
        //time
        clock_t start, finish;

        vector<int> arr(ARR_SIZE);

        generate_arr(arr);

        cout << endl << "Generating finished!" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Array before sorting" << endl << endl;
        print(arr);

        cout << endl << endl;

        cout << "Checking is_sorted finished! The result is " << (is_sorted(arr) == 0? "false": "true") << "." << endl << endl;

        //Добавили задачу в портфель(первую)
        tasks.push( make_pair(0, arr.size() - 1) );

        //==================================================
        start = clock();

        for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++)
            thrs[i] = thread( quick_sort<int>, ref(arr) );

        finish = clock();
        //==================================================

        for (auto& th : thrs)
            th.join();

        cout << "Sorting finished!" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Array after sorting" << endl << endl;
        print(arr);

        cout << endl << endl;

        cout << "Checking is_sorted finished! The result is " << (is_sorted(arr) == 0? "false": "true") << "." << endl << endl;

        cout << "Runtime: " << (double)(finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: У вас объем данных по моему маловат, на таком создание потоков выйдет дороже, чем сортировка в одном потоке.

Comment: @Monk сто тысяч элементов мало? Пробовал на миллионе, разницы нет)

Comment: Тот же вопрос на английском: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334109/quick-sort-with-multithreading-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334109/quick-sort-with-multithreading-in-c)

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov это я задал на англоязычной версии сайта

Comment: @rekrut потому я и написал - "тот же", а не "такой же"

Answer (score 4):

Конечно будет медленнее, у Вас же нет вообще никакой параллельной обработки. Весь Ваш код полностью последователен, хоть и выполняется на разных потоках. А теперь сравните: 2 последовательных кода, но во втором случае создаются потоки, между ними переключаются контексты и т.п. Какой подход будет быстрее?

Что делает Ваш код последовательным? Как минимум, вот эта строчка: `unique_lock<mutex> u_lock(q_mutex);`

Comment: Хорошо, я понял что с синхронизацией я намудрил. Ну а как сделать код параллельным?если не сложно, опишите.

Comment: @rekrut, для этого нужно разработать алгоритм quick sort, который можно раскидать по потокам. При этом, если всё будет происходит на самом массиве, нужно гарантировать, чтобы данные между потоками не пересекались в кэш-линиях, иначе получите пинг-понг и производительность упадёт.

Comment: спасибо!буду пробовать!